# Word to be given to drink

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for a specific word when I want to be given to drink.

If I am hungry I say **feed** me.
If I am thirsty I say ____ me.

I know a person who is given such is said to be fed and watered. But I don't think one can say water me.

Comment: “Give me a drink”

Comment: @Laurel "If I am hungry, I say feed me. If I am thirsty, I say **water** me" sounds very awkward. The same answerer also say, " it's unlikely you would use this for a person". So, no it is not duplicate.

Comment: @Ubihatt It is a duplicate, in that there is no such word.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the word **slake.**

Usage: Slake with [*sth*]

From [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/slake):

> to satisfy a feeling of being thirsty or of wanting something:
>
> > After our long game of tennis, we slaked our thirst with a beer.

Oxford dictionary has few more [example sentences](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/slake).

Answer (score 0):

Although unusual in this context, there is the verb [**libate**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/libate):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> transitive verb
> : to pour out a libation or make libation to
>
> intransitive verb
> 1 : to make libation
> 2 : to drink alcoholic drink
> // sat up with three *libating* guests who would not leave

In theory, as a transitive verb, you *should* be allowed to say:

> If I am hungry, I say feed me. If I am thirsty, I say *libate* me.

At least in terms of its association with *libation*, the word would be understood.

---

In fact, the first Google hit I got on *libate me* returned [*Libate Me with Google Maps*](http://googlemapsmania.blogspot.com/2011/09/libate-me-with-google-maps.html):

> The New Belgium Brewing Company's Libation Location Map uses Google Maps to help you find the nearest locations that stock their many beers.
>
> Using the map you can enter a location and select from the many beers on offer from New Belgium Brewing. You can even select the distance that you are prepared to travel to get your favourite tipple. The Libation Location Map then shows you all the stores near by where you can purchase your beer.

Perhaps ironically, the link to the Libation Location Map it mentions returns a 404 error.

---

Shortly after that on Google are hits on the LGBT+ poem [*A Queerification*](https://www.poets.org/poetsorg/poem/queerification?mbd=1), by Regie Cabico, which includes the lines:

> libate me in halos
> heal me in halls of femmy troubadors

---

Needless to say, however, while *libate* does appear to be a valid verb that can be used in this way, it's extremely uncommon and, due to this, would not be at all idiomatic.

Note, too, that it doesn't seem to exist at Oxford Dictionaries, so it may only be a US verb. But Oxford Dictionaries does say this under its definition of [*libation*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/libation):

> **Origin**
> Late Middle English: from Latin libatio(n-), from libare ‘pour as an offering’.

(The *OED* itself might provide an entry for *libate*, but I don't have access to it.)